# How to check active accordion based on object id?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

Here `{% c_url request 'display' %}` this will return either display class or None. if display class return I want to keep accordion collapse open. But this is opening all the collapse.

I want to apply `display` class to the particular #collapseid only. How can I do it ?

template

```
 {% for n in navs %}
      <li>
        <a
          data-toggle="collapse"
          class="sub{{n.id}} {% c_url request 'active' %}"
          href="#collapse{{n.id}}"
          aria-expanded="true"
          aria-controls="collapse"
          ><p>
            {{n.title}}
          </p></a
        >
        <div class="collapse{{n.id}} {% c_url request 'display' %}"  id="collapse{{n.id}}">
          <ul class="nav">
          {% for i in n.nav_set.all %}
            ..............

          {% endfor %}
        
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li> 
    {% endfor %}
```

c_url template tag

```
@register.simple_tag
def c_url(request, value): 

    if request.resolver_match.url_name in ['url1', 'url2']:
        return value
```

Comment: Not clear what is the logic of 'url1', 'url2'. Do I understand correctly that you need to set class "display" on a certain collapse id? Do you know that id or it's in some variable?

Comment: @EgorWexler url1 and url2 are the url names. If the current url name is in the list then I want to set class `display` on this url's collapse div

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two 'easier' options to do it:

1. Set active status flag on n in navs in context (in **views.py**):

   ```
    for n in navs:
        if <condition for active>:
            n.active = True
   ```

   Then in the template:

   ```
    {% if n.active %}display{% endif %}
   ```
2. Add an additional option to the context for the active collapse id:
   **views.py**:

   ```
    for n in navs:
        if <condition for active>:
            context['active_id'] = n.id
   ```

   Then in the template:

   ```
    {% if n.id == active_id %}display{% endif %}
   ```

Comment: `{% if n.active %}display{% endif %}` this sets displays on all the collapse

Comment: @D_P, I assume that display should be set only on some of navs (depends on your condition). So complete line will look like this `<div class="collapse{{n.id}} {% if n.active %} 'display'{% endif %}"  id="collapse{{n.id}}">` where `n.active = True` is set only on line(s) you wish to be active